# JSONAPI Resources gem not finding resource after adding namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I tried to namespace my resources and controllers, but now when I try to run my server it keeps getting this error:

> JSONAPI: Could not find resource 'categories'. (Class CategoryResource
>   not found)

**controller/api/v1/categories_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
end
```

**resources/api/v1/category_resource.rb**

```
class Api::V1::CategoryResource < JSONAPI::Resource
    attribute :name
    has_many :posts
end
```

I don't know what is triggering this error. I even removed the files and the reference to Category from the `routes.rb`

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      jsonapi_resources :categories
    end
  end
```

This started after I moved the files from the root of `controllers` and `resources` to `api/v1`. What is wrong with my project?

Answer (score 1):

For your `CategoriesController`, try inheriting from `JSONAPI::ResourceController` instead of `ApplicationController`.

```
class Api::V1::CategoriesController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
```